# Qt mouseMoveEvent only when left mouse button is pressed

Tags: qt, events, mouse, move

I currently have a program that draws lines and rectangles.

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

I use mouseMoveEvent to draw temporary preview of a line and when i release i draw the actual line. What I would like to know is how can i make mouseMoveEvent work work only when i have the left mouse button pressed down. I tried the following but then the whole function stops working.

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
     if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
     {
        //do stuff
     }
}
```

but then the function doesn't do anything. Any assistance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 18):

From the documentation of `QMouseEvent::button()`:

> Note that the returned value is always Qt::NoButton for mouse move
>   events.

You should use `buttons()` instead.

```
if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
{
    //do stuff
}
```