# Javascript - left mouse button function executes only once LMB is released

Tags: javascript, function, mouse

I am trying to make an HTML5 game that as long as the player is pressing the LMB, the bullets keep spawning, and once LMB is released, the shooting stops. This is my function:

```
document.onclick = function(mouse){ 
    console.log("Shoot");
}
```

Only once the LMB is released, that message is showing up in the console log. 
I did look over stackoverflow and found this:
[Qt mouseMoveEvent only when left mouse button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279762/qt-mousemoveevent-only-when-left-mouse-button-is-pressed)
But I failed to integrate it into my canvas... it just won't do anything.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If by 'bullets spawning', you mean `console.log("shoot");`,  you just need to use `mousedown` instead of `.onclick`. But if you want some function to keep running (e.g `fireBullet();`) **while** the key is being **held** down, you can refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute code when the mouse is pressed you should be using **mousedown** instead of **onclick**.

Check the **Mouse Events** examples on w3c. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp

Answer (score 1):

"onclick" calls the function on mouse click up. You need a more specific event listener.

What your looking for, assuming your use case is accurate, is "onmousedown".

See this link for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp

Simply replace "onclick" with "onmousedown".

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` method is invoked when you ***release*** the mouse button instead of being held down. What you need is the `mousedown` method.

Also, you need to reword your question a bit. As I understand,

> you want something to happen **while** the mouse key is being ***held***
>   down.

To do that, you need to invoke the `mousedown` activity in some *reasonable interval.*

```
var mousedownID = -1;  //Global ID of mouse down interval
function mousedown(event) {
  if(mousedownID==-1)  //Prevent multimple loops!
     mousedownID = setInterval(whilemousedown, 100 /*execute every 100ms*/);


}
function mouseup(event) {
   if(mousedownID!=-1) {  //Only stop if exists
     clearInterval(mousedownID);
     mousedownID=-1;
   }

}
function whilemousedown() {
   /*put your code here*/
   /* i.e, whatever you what to keep on happening while the button is down*/
}
//Assign events
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
//Also clear the interval when user leaves the window with mouse
document.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseup);
```